# How to sort email by date using IMAP java implementation

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I want to sort email by date so I can get the latest email which has all the conversation and other I can ignore in my code.

**Sample Code:**

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        Store store = session.getStore();
        store.connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD);
        IMAPFolder inbox = (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("INBOX");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        SortTerm[] sortTerms = new SortTerm[1];
        sortTerms[0] = SortTerm.ARRIVAL;
        Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();
```

Answer (score 2):

I see you've discovered [SortTerm](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/SortTerm.html) so you're most of the way there.  Use the [IMAPFolder.getSortedMessages](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html#getSortedMessages-com.sun.mail.imap.SortTerm:A-) method:

```
Message[] messages = ((IMAPFolder)inbox).getSortedMessages(sortTerms);
```

Note that this depends on your server supporting the [SORT extension defined by RFC 5256](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5256.txt).  If it doesn't, you'll have to sort the messages on the client.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why [IMAPFolder.getSortedMessages](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html#getSortedMessages-com.sun.mail.imap.SortTerm:A-)  doesn't contain that fallback code?

Comment: I added this as an IMAP-specific feature because it was relatively easy to implement - the server does all the work. If it was added as a general JavaMail feature, I probably would've added the fallback (as is done for search), but that was more work and it wasn't clear anyone would use it without the IMAP server support.

Comment: seems like not working anymore for Jakarta EE mail?