# Gmail: Java mail API gets only emails from 2018 and below

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

This is my code:

```
public void check() throws MessagingException, Exception {
    String host = "pop.gmail.com";
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    properties.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "pop3s");
    properties.put("mail.pop3s.port", "995");
    properties.put("mail.pop3s.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.pop3s.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
    properties.put("mail.pop3s.auth", "true");
    // properties.put("mail.debug", "true");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

    // create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
    Store store = session.getStore("pop3s");

    store.connect(
            host,
            "username",
            "password");
    // create the folder object and open it
    Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

    Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();

    Message message = messages[0];
    System.out.println("=================MSG 0===================");
    System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
    System.out.println("Date: " + message.getSentDate());

    Message messageLast = messages[messages.length - 1];
    System.out.println("=================MSG LAST===================");
    System.out.println("Subject: " + messageLast.getSubject());
    System.out.println("Date: " + messageLast.getSentDate());

    emailFolder.close(false);
    store.close();
}
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting only messages that are from 2018 and below, I can't get the new emails! Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the error messages.

Comment: Can we assume that "password" is a valid access token?

Comment: there is no error message, the password is correct because I get the emails... but the issue I get only emails of 2018 and below

Comment: TBH im surprised its working at all mixing mail.pop3s.auth with a password.

Comment: what's the right way? I actually copy pasted this from another source, but it worked!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50983353/1841839